# Not understanding given byte and position in UnicodeDecodeError error message

Tags: python, csv, encoding, utf-8

I have a csv file which looks like this:

```
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;
VESELÝ
```

So these are exactly 40 lines containing a row with "Thisisatext;" and so on and the last one has a name with a special accent on the y.

I now tried to open this file with the following python code:

```
import csv
myfile = r'S:\folder\myfile.csv'

with open(myfile) as infile: #,  encoding="utf-8-sig" # , encoding="cp1252"
        cr = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=";")
        for line in cr:
            print(line)
```

Which does not work and leads to an error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 57: character maps to <undefined>
```

And indeed, reason is that I should use an encoding specifiyng utf-8-sig. The error message comes, as it seems by my operating system the standard is cp1252. When I try it with cp1252 I get the same error. When I try it with utf-8-sig it works. As the character y with the accent is contained in the utf 8 encoding while it seems that it is not in the cp1252.

When I open the file in notepad++ and place the cursor to the point in the row 41 where the Ý stands, it says position 8248. When I mark the Ý and use the notepad++ converter to convert ascii to hex, it displays:

[image: ex1]

The python error message says `can't decode byte 0x9d in position 57`.

When I remove one line (for example the first one) according to notepad++ the Ý now stands at the position 8042. When I run the code on the new file again, I get the error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 8043: character maps to <undefined>
```

So now the position is 8043. As (almost) stated in notepad++.

I have two questions:

**First one**: Why does the python error message mention byte 0x9d? When I check the converted result in notepad++ it looks like in the image, C39D? So 0x tells me that python is talking about hex and when I check 9d [here](https://www.garykessler.net/library/ascii.html) it says:

> "NOTE: Decimal 128-129 (0x80-81), 141-144 (0x8D-90) and 157-158
> (0x9D-9E) are non-printable characters."

But why is the notepad++ converted result C39D? According to [this](https://www.garykessler.net/library/ascii.html) table C3 would be `î`.

In general I suppose that the accent 9D which can be added to different characters is the problem. But I am not understanding the details.

**Second one:** Why and how does python calculate the position? Clearly there is a big mismatch in the first case, when python says `'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 57`. How does python come up with 57? And when I remove one line it suddently is correct with a complete different number. It seems like python reads in the file in parts and gives me the position within a specific part? Is it possible to get the "real" correct position? If I have a very large file and cannot manually search it, how can I identify the exact position of the sign causing problems?

Comment: what information do you get with different scenarios [as this page describes](https://johnlekberg.com/blog/2020-04-03-codec-errors.html) ? And do you have a (minimal) example of the actual file in question for download somewhere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second question, if you run the code in a debugger, you'll see the code returns an exception (not exactly the same as yours, but close:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    for line in cr:
  File "D:\dev\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 54: character maps to <undefined>
```

In my debugger, the value of `input` is:

```
[Dbg]>>> input
b'isisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;Thisisatext;\r\nVESEL\xc3\x9d\r\n'
[Dbg]>>> hex(input[54])
'0x9d'
```

The takeaway is that the offset is in the current chunk of the file being read and not the offset in the entire file.  Based on the file being slightly more than 8K in size and that the offset changes to slightly less than 8K when a line is deleted, the file is likely read in 8K chunks.  To locate the correct location in the file read it all at once and decode it as a continuous blob of data:

```
>>> with open('myfile.csv', 'rb') as f:
...     data = f.read()
...     
>>> data.decode('cp1252')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\dev\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 15, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 8246: character maps to <undefined>
>>> hex(data[8246])
'0x9d'
```

8246 is the actual offset of byte 0x9D in the file.

For the first question, `C3 9D` *together* make the multibyte UTF-8 encoding of `Ý`.  In [cp1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), `C3` decodes as `Ã` but `9D` is undefined.  If you decode up to but not including offset 8246 it works without error, which is why it excepts on `9D`:

```
>>> data[8240:8246].decode('cp1252')
'VESELÃ'
```

Comment: It's the readers underlying `open` which do the reading and decoding, even if `csv.reader` is requesting the file in chunks. I'm fairly sure the location reported by the reader is the actual offset within the file, not the chunk. But I'm not 100% confident in that.

Comment: @deceze I'm 100% confident that it is the offset in the chunk, as that's exactly the content of the buffer in the debugger.  The failing offset in the file is 8246 and subtracting 8192 (8K) is 54...the offset in the error message.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thanks for this! Interesting. Where can I read more about the processing in chunks and if it is really 8192? Where is it documented? I have really large files, so I am a bit sceptical about reading the file all at once. So I hoped for a simple solution for a code around to somehow multiply the chunks size times the current number of chunks where it interrupts and then somehow get the correct position out of it. But for this I have to implement a counter which counts the number of chunks, like a "running i" so to say which gets incremented by one each time a new chunk is started.

Comment: @PSt see the *buffering* parameter of [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, looking at an Extended ASCII table doesn't help when you're dealing with CP1252. You can find the table for CP1252 here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252.

> Why does the python error message mention byte `0x9d`? When I check the converted result in notepad++ it looks like in the image, `C39D`?

Yes, you have the two bytes `C3 9D` in your file. `0x..` is just another notation to clarify that it means hex bytes. In context it should be understood that `C3 9D` is already in hex notation without repeating "0x.." for each byte. So `0x9d` refers to your `9D` byte.

`C3` is a mapped code in the CP1252 table and maps to the character "Ã". `9D` is *not* mapped in the CP1252 table though and has no meaning, just as the error message says.

In UTF-8, the byte sequence `C3 9D` maps to the character "Ý", as expected.

> Why and how does python calculate the position? Clearly there is a big mismatch in the first case, when python says `'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 57`.

That probably means that you have another weird byte originally at position 57, probably in your first row. If you delete that, the next "error" Python encounters is at position 8043 then.

You may be interested in [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) for some primer on encodings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however regarding another weird byte at position 57: No, I can also delete another row and there is only this one character that makes a problem. So this is not the case. There must be another reason.

Comment: Then we need a [mre] to be able to diagnose that. The best thing to do is to look at the file with a hex editor and check out position 57.

Comment: The file is exactly as I put it in here, just copy and paste and save as csv.

Comment: Not necessarily. Copy and pasting *characters* which this web site has re-encoded as part of its processing will have removed any stray unprintable bytes which may have existed in your original file.

Comment: No, I copied it manually too. This is my file.

Comment: Not sure what that means, but, well, can't reproduce like this.